# Mongoose property filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm looking for the equivalent of virtuals for existing properties. I would like to modify a value for an existing schema property when I call it (such as strip tags or whatever). I am currently using a virtual with a different name to achieve this. Evidently Mongoose breaks when a virtual has the same name as existing properties. Doesn't seem to be any pre/post fetch filters - suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're saying you have a different "external" format than is internally stored...

There's no way to completely override the get/set in a 100% consistent way without diving deep into the internals of Mongoose. I've done some exploring recently of that, and it's a deep dark hole. :(

You've got a few reasonable options:

1. Virtual property approach. You could have a property actually called `_color` and then expose it as `color` for example rather than trying to overload the same value. Then, it would be clear (maybe by convention), that the underscore prefixed values are "internal-use-only."
2. Add a function to get/set the value (by adding a function to the Schema). I like this one as you could add a function called `toColorString` or something like that so that it would be clear when/how to use it.

If you use virtual/hidden properties, it makes querying the document a bit more confusing as the property isn't exposed either as the same name or in quite the same way as the data would be queried. So, that's why I'd lean a bit to using custom functions if possible to fetch custom formatted versions of a given property/field.

Comment: Ya - it's what I found as well. I'm fine with the virtuals - used to their quirks. Was just hoping for some automatic pre processing on fetch like there is for save.

Comment: The thing is ... you don't really want to change the data when it's loaded. You only want its appearance to consumers to change. That's different. You'd really want to keep the "raw" data.

Comment: Yes I agree - my current situation is that I need to modify some data - things is that it us used in many places. So I can either change it all over the place ( i.e. add some filtering) or deal with it once as I would like.